# What connection does RDP default to when host machine is on wifi and ethernet?

Tags: wifi, rdp, ethernet

When the host machine I'm connecting to is currently on both the docked (ethernet) and wireless version of our network, which one does RDP default to when I initiate Remote Assistance?

Answer (score 3):

It is connecting to the IP address the hostname resolves to, and therefore to the adapter that has that particular IP address.

You can verify the fact using `netstat` on the command line, it shows the open TCP connections and the addresses on both ends.

Comment: Does a laptop on Ethernet and Wi-Fi have two IP addresses assigned simultaneously in a DHCP environment?

Comment: Yes, both will have a separate IP address. Only if they are in the same L2 bridge, they can share an IP address, but that is very rare. You can check the IP addresses with `ipconfig` on the command line.

Comment: So this doesn't really answer the question then. When one hostname resolves to two IP addresses, which one is RDP defaulting to?

Comment: It does answer the question as it was written. The answer you were seeking cannot be given with the information you provided in the question.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a function of RDP. It's a function of DNS. Whichever A record is returned first in the order in the DNS query answer is the ip address that RDP will use to connect to. More specifically, this is a function of the Round Robin feature of DNS.

In the two captures below taken while querying for the A record of my desktop computer from two different computers you'll see that my DNS server has used Round Robin to re-order the answer to each client. The first client gets one A record first and the other client gets the other A record first.

[image]

[image]